# Polynomial $f$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: functions, polynomials, terminology

I came across a question which asks to find all polynomials $f$ over $\mathbb{C}$.
Does this mean the coefficients of the polynomial can be complex or the polynomial can take complex values?

Comment: it means the coefficients of the polynomial are in $\mathbb C$

Comment: Are you sure the question is not asking for all irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  [polynomials over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring#Definition_(univariate_case))  $\Bbb C$ (or more generally any field $\Bbb K$) are expressions of the form

$p_0+p_1X+p_2X^2+\cdots+p_{m-1}X^{m-1}+p_mX^m$,

where $X$ is an indeterminate and $p_0,p_1,p_2,...,p_{m-1},p_{m}$ are in $\Bbb C$ (or more generally $\Bbb K$).

Comment: What is K?
${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I use the letter $\mathbb K$ to denote any [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics))

Comment: Thanks ${}{}{}{}$